# How do I replace a big chuck of code with another chunk of code via JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a php page that I am calling via ajax and the returned value i want to place in the page as a new element. For example I have

```
<div id="main">

<div class="element">
 Old stuff
 ....
</div>
<div class="element">
 ....
</div>
<div class="element">
 ....
</div>

</div>
```

This is my page

I have a php page I am calling view Jquery ajax that returns this structure

```
<div id="main">

<div class="element">
 New stuff
 ....
</div>
<div class="element">
 ....
</div>
<div class="element">
 ....
</div>

</div>
```

So i need to hide the old stuff and replace it with the new block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery ajax actually has a shortcut for that, if you want to replace the contents of your "main" div:

```
$("#main").load("myAjaxPHPURL.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'ajax/myajax.php',
   success: function(data) {
   $('#main').html(data);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main').html("New markup to replace");
```

Will replace the content of the div within id=main.

```
$('#main').append("New markup added to end of target");
```

Will add the content to the end leaving the original content intact.

```
$('#main').prepend("New markup added to beginning of target");
```

Will add the content to the top leaving the original content intact.

Answer (score 0):

Or...

$('#main').replaceWith($jq(newHtml));

That way you don't have to strip out the outer div from the new content.